# How to manage dbcontext in layered asp.net web application using EF 4.x

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, entity-framework-4.1, poco, dbcontext

There are four projects in a solution: DAL, BOL, UI and Model.

Model contains POCO classes and DAL is just contains a DbContext class with models introduced inside it. All projects have a reference to Model project, UI has a reference to BOL and BOL has a reference to DAL.

The current method for example to save data is:
In UI after pressing the Submit button, the data of form stores in a model POCO class, the POCO class goes to BOL save method, when the BOL is instantiated the dbcontext also instantiates, and the save method uses that dbcontext to submit changes.

The question: Is instantiating dbcontext like this efficient?  Should I do something else to achieve more performance? I'm trying to have the most possible performance because lots of records at a same time may be inserted into database.

Comment: If you want to insert a bunch of records as one unit of work it would make sense to use one context instance. If however you are referring to massive concurrency (_at a same time_) each call would have its own context. Which of the two did you mean?

Comment: Well it is better to make it general. I'm going to build methods and classes in lower layers for programmers, so they can just call them from upper layers to insert/update/delete/load data. They don't need to worry about connections, dbcontexts, ... and should just focus on business.
According to your comments, instantiating dbcontext in BOL constructors is correct but programmers should use one instance of BOL if they need to insert a bunch of records at the same time.
You can reply this suggestion as a post reply and I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: OK, but I think for the most it's you own thinking and elaboration so I would feel better if you'd answer your own question (which is fine at Stack Overflow) and mark it as accepted (possible after 2 days).

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, DbContext and EF still use ADO.NET connection mechanisms to connect to a database, so they still make use of ADO.NET connection pooling and things like that.  That being said, you don't want to keep a DBContext open for longer than you need to, because then that will hold a connection from the connection pool, and the connection will be idle more often than not.  Create you DBContext in a using statement whenever you need it.

Comment: In a BOL class I might have 3 methods to connect to database, you mean it is better to use a using statement in each method?
And if I want to insert 100 records by calling a method, is it efficient to call that method that contains a "using" statement and every time it makes a new dbcontext?